# How to while loop correctly in bash script?

Tags: bash

I have wrote this script which takes a stop and start number and counts out the numbers in between - I am yting to get it to keep increasing no matter whether the "stop" number is reaced or not so it keeps counting until ctrl+z is pressed but it is not recognising the while condition for me - could anyone correct the syntax for me please ?

```
  #!/bin/sh

stopvalue=$1
startvalue=$2

if [ $# -ne 2  ]
then
   echo "Error - You must enter two numbers exactly - using default start value of 1"
#exit 0
fi

echo ${startvalue:=1}

while (test "$startvalue" -le "$stopvalue" ||  "$startvalue" -ge "$stopvalue")
do
       startvalue=$((startvalue+1))
        echo $startvalue
done
```

Answer (score 14):

Now that you have two answers about the while loop, I'll suggest using `for` loop instead:

```
for((i=$startvalue;i<=$stopvalue;++i)) do
   echo $i
done
```

Answer (score 5):

Your main problem is in your condition:

```
while (test "$startvalue" -le "$stopvalue" ||  "$startvalue" -ge "$stopvalue")
```

You are telling it to continue if `$startvalue` is (less than or equal to) or (greater than or equal to) `$stopvalue`.  For ANY combination of `$startvalue` and `$stopvalue`, the one will be less than, equal to, or greater than the other.  Take out the second condition so that it only continues if `$startvalue` is less than or equal to `$stopvalue`.

And you should write it:

```
while [ "$startvalue" -le "$stopvalue" ]
```

Answer (score 5):

I use the simple while loop program. Which works for me. as per my understanding before passing any variable in while loop we have to declare it:

```
sum=0            
temp=1          
while [ $temp -ne 0 ]           
do              
echo "Enter number: OR 0 to Quit :"             
read temp          
sum=`expr $sum + $temp`          
done          
echo $sum
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while [ "$startvalue" -le "$stopvalue" -o "$startvalue" -ge "$stopvalue" ]
do
       startvalue=$((startvalue+1))
       echo $startvalue
done
```

Comment: That's still going to loop forever because `$startvalue` is always less than (first condition), equal to (both), or greater than (second) `$stopvalue`.

Comment: @Kevin - Good point, I didn't spend much time looking at whether or not the loop made sense, I was just fixing the syntax.

Comment: This is correct syntax. In test you have to use **-o** and not **||**. || is totally different thing and after that you need another shell command (like test).

Comment: you can use `||` with `[[ ]]`, like `[[ condition || condition ]]`

Answer (score -2):

```
startvalue=50
stopvalue=0
while [ $startvalue -lt  $stopvalue -o $startvalue -ne $stopvalue ]; do
echo "Enter number equal to the start value: :"             
read stopvalue
done
```

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.